# Описание вопроса не прижато к правой стороне на главной странице

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, список-вопросов

Почему бы текст *"задан 4 минуты назад ..."* не прижать к правой стороне на главной странице? Это баг или раньше так не было?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366481/339911

Comment: херакс херакс - в продакшн!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас [выглядит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) пофикшенным:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уже [status-completed]